# Switching from single to multi language website - indexing problem and lost rank

Tags: seo, url, internationalization, migration, hreflang

I have a website which used to be to available in a single language website: French.  We wanted to purpose our product in other language (English, Portuguese, Spanish, etc.)

First, we have changed the URL structure by adding a language prefix:

#### Old Schema

- `https://mywebsite.example` => French
- Defaut language : French

#### New Schema

- `https://mywebsite.example/fr` => French
- `https://mywebsite.example/en` => English
- `https://mywebsite.example/es` => Spanish
- etc ..

In addition, we added hreflang meta tags

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://mywebsite.example/en" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="https://mywebsite.example/fr" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://mywebsite.example/de" />
etc..
```

When users go to `https://mywebsite.example`, they get redirected to the language according to its browser. But the user has also the ability to switch language thank to a language menu.

The default language is English.

We have deployed this new version 10 days ago, and we have noticed that the French version (which had a strong SEO reputation) has been completely wiped out of the French version of Google.

There's no error in the search console. What mistake did we make? Is it a question of time? I uploaded an XML sitemap, but I don't think it's a crawl problem.

Comment: What does "the default language is English" mean?    Does that mean that Googlbot always gets redirected to the English site?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, on the root path ('/'). But there is an switching menu, which contains the other language path. Also, we don't redirect from one language to another. (meaning that a english speaker can browse on the french version).